# How do you determine a processing time in J?

Tags: j

I created a program to analyze text data, and now I am trying to calculate program runtime in J.

I am trying to create the matrix like below and reading J books, but I am not sure how to do such thing

```
┌─────────────────┬────┐
│number of article│time│
├─────────────────┼────┤
│0                │0   │
├─────────────────┼────┤
│1                │2   │
├─────────────────┼────┤
│2                │4   │
├─────────────────┼────┤
│3                │6   │
├─────────────────┼────┤
│4                │8   │
├─────────────────┼────┤
│5                │10  │
├─────────────────┼────┤
│6                │12  │
├─────────────────┼────┤
│7                │14  │
├─────────────────┼────┤
│8                │16  │
├─────────────────┼────┤
│9                │18  │
└─────────────────┴────┘
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: High level timings can be obtained with ‘timespacex ‘phrase to profile’`. More detailed timings, for optimization purposes, can be obtained by using the J Performance Monitor, which is founded on the primitives described here: http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx006.htm . And packaged up in a convent script / addon, detailed here: http://www.jsoftware.com/release/pm.htm .

Comment: Also if you do find the performance to be insufficient, try seeing if any of the [Special Combinations](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/SpecialCombinations) are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6! : 2 ''

Use this foreign conjunction

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use jpm package

load 'jpm'